# Alternative formating of units in plot labels

Tags: python-xarray

When **plotting xarry DataArrays**, I would like to select a **different formatting of the units in plotting labels**, e.g. `mass (kg)` or `mass in kg` instead of the default backets `units [kg]`.
If've found a similar comment (https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/2151#pullrequestreview-121662163) but no other.

As I see it, it is currently hard-coded in file https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/main/xarray/plot/utils.py (see code below)

```py
def _get_units_from_attrs(da):
    """Extracts and formats the unit/units from a attributes."""
    pint_array_type = DuckArrayModule("pint").type
    units = " [{}]"
    if isinstance(da.data, pint_array_type):
        units = units.format(str(da.data.units))
    elif da.attrs.get("units"):
        units = units.format(da.attrs["units"])
    elif da.attrs.get("unit"):
        units = units.format(da.attrs["unit"])
    else:
        units = ""
    return units
```

Is there a solution for me to change the units formatting style? Thanks!

Comment: rather than changing xarray's behavior, you can always modify the plot using matplotlib. For example, `ax.set_ylabel('mass in kg')`. There is no way to specify a different units display format within xarray though.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thanks for your answer. Yes, that's obviously the way to go then... But in the meantme I came up with a new idea using a projection class. I edited the question above showing this solution: Everytime xarray calls `set_xlabel` or `set_ylabel` I manipulate the label if the last character is "]". Works fine for me, maybe not for everybody, but it is a solution without having to write the additional `ax.set_ylable(...)` myself everytime to fix the label.

Comment: if you have an answer to your own question, it's preferred that you [post it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than editing your question to include an answer

Comment: did that now below

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found a workaround using a matplotlib projection class:

```py
class XarrayLabelManipulation(plt.Axes):
    def _adjust_units_label(self, label, units_format='in'):
        if label:
            # other formats: '(', '[', '/', 'in'
            if not label[-1] == ']':
                return label
            if units_format== '[':
                return label
            idx0 = label.rfind('[', 1)
            units_string = label[idx0:]
            if units_format== 'in':
                return label.replace(units_string, f' in {units_string[1:-1]}')
            if units_format== '/':
                return label.replace(units_string, f' / {units_string[1:-1]}')
            if units_format== '(in)':
                return label.replace(units_string, f' ({units_string[1:-1]})')

    def set_xlabel(self, xlabel, *args, **kwargs):
        super().set_xlabel(self._adjust_units_label(xlabel), *args, **kwargs)

    def set_ylabel(self, ylabel, *args, **kwargs):
        super().set_ylabel(self._adjust_units_label(ylabel), *args, **kwargs)

proj.register_projection(XarrayLabelManipulation)
```